Question about 2D-Fresnel integration
Thank you for reading my question!
I am trying to get the following integration:
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{j(a(x-x_0)^2+b(y-y_0)^2+c(x-x_0)(y-y_0))}dxdy
\end{align*}
$$
The problem can be easily solved if $c=0$ since the original integration will become
$$
\begin{align*}
&\int_0^\infty\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{j(a(x-x_0)^2+b(y-y_0)^2)}dxdy\\
=&\int_0^\infty e^{j(a(x-x_0)^2)}dx\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{j(b(y-y_0)^2)}dy\\
\end{align*}
$$
which can be represented by fresnel integration. But when $c$ is non-zero. I have no idea how to deal with it.
To put it in another form, the integration is
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{j[x-x_0,y-y_0]\frac{H}{2}[x-x_0,y-y_0]^T}dxdy
\end{align*}
$$
where $H$ is a Hessian matrix and it is p.s.d.
I know that we can transform $H$ into a diagonal matrix with appropriate coordinate transformation. But at the same time, the integration would be dependent, which is intractable for me.
Any help is appreciated. Reference for 2D-Fresnel (if it exists, I don't know due to my ignorance) is welcomed.
Thank you for finishing reading my question. Hope it is interesting for you.
